# Access to path is denied when trying to import from the client's desktop with SSIS

Tags: vb.net, excel, ssis

I'm creating a html page that will import an excel file in to a tracking system.  On a button click event excel file is located / ssis package is fired / data imported then closed out.  Thats the idea work flow.  Problem is the excel file access is being denied before the package even executes

Here is the exact error :[image]

I've tried :

- excel file properties have been shared to everyone
- identity impersonate set to true
- hard coding the path

here is the VB code

```
    Protected Sub bntExecute_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnExecute.Click

    Dim app As Application = New Application()
    Dim package As Package = Nothing
    'Dim fileName As String = "C:\Users\Desktop\T. Bryant III\PTSID_Update_Template"'

    Try
        Dim fileName As String = Server.MapPath(System.IO.Path.GetFileName(FileUpload1.PostedFile.FileName.ToString()))

        FileUpload1.PostedFile.SaveAs(fileName)

        package = app.LoadPackage("@C:\Users\Desktop\T.Bryant III\KitImport", Nothing)

        'excel connection from package'
        package.Connections("SourceConnectionExcel").ConnectionString = "provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0data source =" + fileName + "Extended Properties = Excel 8.0"

        'Execute the pakage'
        Dim results As Microsoft.SqlServer.Dts.Runtime.DTSExecResult = package.Execute()

    Catch ex As Exception
        Throw ex 

    Finally
        package.Dispose()
        package = Nothing
    End Try

End Sub
```

Thanks in advance or if there is an easier way to do this please let me know.  The package when executing it in ssis works fine with its own connection manager etc.

Comment: No idea of ssis issues - don't even no what it stands for... The "@C:\..." if a C# convention (or may it is a ssis convention?) - get rid of the @ and try.
It looks like the "package", whatever that is, is the code opening the file. Try using a folder outside of protected areas.

Comment: What is the exact error message you are getting?

Comment: @rheitzman SSIS also known as a DTSX package in 2012 now its Business Intelligence integration service

Comment: The message is clear - the application pool's account doesn't have permissions to read from the user's desktop folder (obviously). What are you trying to do? An SSIS package will *always* run on a server and *never* have to read anything from the user's desktop

Comment: I suspect this is *not* the code that produced the error. The error mentions the hard-coded path to a desktop file. IIS has no access to a user's desktop. Does the error *also* occur when you occur when you remove the hard-coded path, or was this a typo?

Answer (score 0):

A few things to try. If they don't work for you as permanent solutions, they should at least confirm that your code is working and you are dealing with a persmissions issue (which appears to be the case).

- Move your file to the public folder (C:\Users\Public).
- Run your application (or web browser) as an administrator (if applicable to your version of Windows).
- If you are using a web browser, try using a different one.
- If nothing else works, try pasting your code into a Windows Form Application.

If you still get the same error after trying all of this, it's time to take another look at your code. Remove the Try/Catch block to determine precisely which line is throwing the error. If you've tried hard coding, I'm guessing it's the SaveAs method. I'm not sure what class FileUpload1 is, but some SaveAs methods won't overwrite existing files unless you explicitly tell them to. Check the appropriate documentation and see if you don't need to pass a True value somewhere along with filename.

Update us with the results. At the very least, this should narrow down your problem and allow for a better diagnosis of it.

Comment: Good points.  I have moved the file to a shared network drive which has at least let me move on to actually executing the package loading but there is an error there and is another totally different question that I'm researching now.

Comment: @TroyBryant SSIS is a server-side technology. These suggestions are about the client side. What are you trying to do and why is SSIS trying to access the *client's* desktop? Put/upload the files on the server or a network share where the application pool has read access and load the data from there

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos the client needs to be able to import their excel information in to the tracking system.

Comment: That's not what I asked. SSIS is strictly server side. In fact, if you install it on your web server, you have to pay *another full* SQL Server license. Anyway, it seems the error has to do with the hardcoded path you used - does it also occur if you try to open the *uploaded* file? Also note that you may have more security issues if you try to load the SSIS package from your desktop instead of a location where IIS has access. Why don't you put the files in your project's folder?

Comment: Ditto - note that a hardcoded path is OK, it just has to be a path that is on the server that the "package" runs on. If the local server path is shared others can access it with the proper permissions.